# Spark Notebook crashes while exporting a huge data frame as CSV file in Scala

Tags: csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using [Spark Notebook](http://spark-notebook.io/) to process a huge number of Tweets. My final result is stored in a `dataframe`. While I try to export it as a CSV file, it shows an error though I used the same method before for exporting small dataset. Any suggestions, please?

- Spark Notebook 0.7.0
- Scala 2.10.6
- Spark 2.0.1
- Hadoop 2.7.2

**Scala code for exporting dataframe**

```
df.coalesce(1)
  .write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
  .option("header", "true")
  .save("/home/shoeb/results")
```

**Error Message**

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:133)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:510)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:211)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:194)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:98)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:105)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:107)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:109)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:111)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:113)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:115)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:117)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:119)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:121)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:123)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:125)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:127)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:129)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:131)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:133)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:135)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:137)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:139)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:141)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:143)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:145)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:147)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:149)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:151)
    at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:153)
    at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:155)
    at $iwC.<init>(<console>:157)
    at <init>(<console>:159)
    at .<init>(<console>:163)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at .<init>(<console>:7)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at $print(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1046)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1327)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:822)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:853)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:801)
    at notebook.kernel.Repl$$anonfun$6.apply(Repl.scala:202)
    at notebook.kernel.Repl$$anonfun$6.apply(Repl.scala:202)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
    at scala.Console$.withOut(Console.scala:126)
    at notebook.kernel.Repl.evaluate(Repl.scala:201)
    at notebook.client.ReplCalculator$$anonfun$10$$anon$1$$anonfun$27.replEvaluate$1(ReplCalculator.scala:402)
    at notebook.client.ReplCalculator$$anonfun$10$$anon$1$$anonfun$27.apply(ReplCalculator.scala:415)
    at notebook.client.ReplCalculator$$anonfun$10$$anon$1$$anonfun$27.apply(ReplCalculator.scala:396)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 16 in stage 5.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 16.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 98, localhost): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/blockmgr-bacb743a-120b-4b06-aecc-606755c69cf8/2a/temp_shuffle_3b5b834c-6477-4849-8915-1f7afaff6f14 (Too many open files)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.open(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.write(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:150)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1454)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1442)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1441)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1441)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:811)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1667)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1622)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1611)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:632)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1890)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1903)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1923)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:143)
    ... 77 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/blockmgr-bacb743a-120b-4b06-aecc-606755c69cf8/2a/temp_shuffle_3b5b834c-6477-4849-8915-1f7afaff6f14 (Too many open files)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.open(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskBlockObjectWriter.write(DiskBlockObjectWriter.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:150)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: You need to increase the open file handle limit on your OS... This isn't necessarily a Spark problem, nor is there a fix for that code

Comment: Also, I don't think you're writing to Hadoop, you're writing to local disk... `java.io.FileOutputStream.open0`, or you're just running Hadoop locally, which would definitely explain the open file handles being too high

Comment: @cricket_007 do you mean to use ulimit command? Also, how can I use hdfs? I simply downloaded the notebook from the website and ran the notebook from bin/spark-notebook. Thanks

Comment: @cricket_007 increased the open file handle limit doesn't help, still getting the same error.

Comment: You say "Hadoop 2.7.2"... If you didn't actually setup and configure YARN and HDFS (there's a Hadoop Apache document for that) , and you're just running Spark code, it's using your local filesystem, not a Hadoop cluster

Comment: And AFAIK, a ulimit change requires a reboot to take effect

Comment: In any case, my suggestion would be actually setup a Mysql or Postgres database to write the dataframe into. CSV is a poor format for later analysis such as from Twitter

Comment: You are right, I don't have hadoop and yarn. Yeah I did restart and the change has been reflected.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR;** Don't use `coalesce(1)`.

While useful in some cases, when data is small enough, `coalesce(1)` moves data to a single worker node, and possibly, escalates this back to the source.

Therefore it is inherently not scalable and should be avoided. Almost all tools these days can, one way or another, read multiple files, and if you really need one file, using dedicated utilities is a much better choice.